# How to use Spring Data Redis for Hash with custom converters and pipelineing

Tags: java-8, spring-data-redis

If I have the following object that I'm storing in redis as Hash

```
@RedisHash("animals")
public class Animal implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5905326889964459171L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String type;
    @Indexed
    private String location;
```

If are 1000 entries in `smembers animals:type:animal01`
and I want to - "Find animals of type animals01 across all locations" then I'm doing -

```
Set<String> members = stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().members("animals:type:animal01");
List<Object> result = stringRedisTemplate.executePipelined(new RedisCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
                for (String member : members) {
                    connection.hGetAll(String.format("animals:%s", member).getBytes());
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Each object in "result" is of type LinkedHashMap. I've tried to used `org.springframework.data.redis.hash.ObjectHashMapper` to convert this to Animal but, it seems ObjectHashMapper only works with Map. I couldn't make it work with Map

(I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-redis 1.5.14.RELEASE, which brings in jedis2.9.0)

How do I deserialize the pipelined results?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hGetAll, I did hMGet. In this case, each object in the result was List. Then I deserialized each of the items in the list. It worked out for me

But I was hoping if there is a better way where spring-redis handles the deserialization part